# Get rectangular Grid coordinates from a plot using R

Tags: r, spatial

Let's say I've generated a random plot in R and then placed horizontal grids:

```
x<-rnorm(100, 12, 3)
y<-rnorm(100, 34, 45)
plot(x,y)
#griding in y direction only
grid(NA, 25, lwd = 2)
```

The plot can be found here: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6GUNg-8d30vUVhMS3ZUa0lULVU/edit?usp=sharing. I want to know: (i) how I'd limit a grid to the maximum and minimum horizontal extent of my data in that particular grid?; i.e. there will be no grid on left/right where I don't have data, given that the height of my grids remain the same (I don't mind making it a spatial object if necessary); and, (ii) How to export/get the coordinates of each rectangular grid afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

This should answer your i).
You can use clip() to set the region of a plot to which you want to add.

```
x<-rnorm(100, 12, 3)
y<-rnorm(100, 34, 45)
plot(x,y)

clip(x1=min(x), x2=max(x), y1=min(y), y2=max(y))
grid(NA, 25, lwd = 2)
```

For ii), you can dig around grid() to find that it uses the following code (slightly modified here) to calculate the Y coordinates of your grid lines,

```
ny <- 25
U <- par("usr")
at <- seq.int(U[3L], U[4L], length.out = ny + 1)
Y <- at[-c(1, ny + 1)]
```

where Y is a vector.

Comment: I think my question was slightly obscured, the solution you gave limit my grids to the whole database's max and min, but i want the extent to be delimited for data located in each horizontal grid (I've just made an edit in my question which makes it clear)!

Comment: So you mean, for every horizontal line, only draw it 'to the extent of your data'. Do you mean in that bin in between the grid lines? A more specific example would help here.

Comment: yes you are correct, I'm still trying and almost figured out a way to do so, will post as soon as I'm done. thanks